# Python: determine if a string contains math?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, python-3.5

Given these strings:

```
"1 + 2"
"apple,pear"
```

How can I use Python 3(.5) to determine that the first string contains a math problem and **nothing else** and that the second string does not?

Comment: I know :P use eval :P lol

Comment: use it only if you trust the input, and it's not from the user

Comment: `eval` obviously won't well ('cause `'x, y'` is a pretty valid statement in python yielding a tuple). Likely you need to write your own calculator, with a limited number of operations.

Comment: but it will tell, like in my answer

Comment: Take a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

Comment: Define "math problem". Simple arithmetic, are brackets allowed, what operators etc.

Comment: Perhaps you could see if `sympy` thinks it's a valid expression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
import ast

UNARY_OPS = (ast.UAdd, ast.USub)
BINARY_OPS = (ast.Add, ast.Sub, ast.Mult, ast.Div, ast.Mod)

def is_arithmetic(s):
    def _is_arithmetic(node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Num):
            return True
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Expression):
            return _is_arithmetic(node.body)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp):
            valid_op = isinstance(node.op, UNARY_OPS)
            return valid_op and _is_arithmetic(node.operand)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):
            valid_op = isinstance(node.op, BINARY_OPS)
            return valid_op and _is_arithmetic(node.left) and _is_arithmetic(node.right)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unsupported type {}'.format(node))

    try:
        return _is_arithmetic(ast.parse(s, mode='eval'))
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        return False
```

Comment: Likely, `ast.UnaryOp` should be handled as well, but I've upvoted this one

Comment: @user3159253 You are absolutely right, thanks! I have added a test for UnaryOp.

Comment: Now I cannot tell if it was copied from here. However, this code appears on GitHub with a Cisco license: https://github.com/chrivand/sample_python_vulns/blob/main/py_solv00.py
However the first commit was 2022.
It would be awesome if these code samples could validate their source and/or explicitly specify a license for it if written by hand (like it seems in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use split(), then iterate through the list to check if all instance are either numerical values or operational values. Then use eval.

```
input = "1 + 2"
for i in input.split():
    if i in ['+','-','*','%','.'] or i.isdigit():
        pass
        # do something
    else:
        pass
        # one element is neither a numerical value or operational value
```

Comment: I won't downvote, but actually it's a pretty complex, error-prone and fragile way to write DSL parsers

Comment: what about scientific notation for numbers ? :)

Comment: This is basically an idea or concept of how to parse it rather then "trusting the source and using eval" immediately.

Comment: For scientific notation, simply add those in your case statements. Snowball from here.

Comment: So `e1` would be equally valid as `1e1` ? :) Fellow, trust me, you've stepped onto a swampy path!

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess that opens to to another answer to parse complex mathematical string equations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parsing library such as [pyPEG](https://fdik.org/pyPEG/), although there is room for improvment do more than this you could define a grammar like this:

```
from pypeg2 import optional, List, Namespace
import re

number = re.compile(r'\d+')
binop = re.compile(r'\+|\*') # Exercise: Extend to other binary operators


class BinOp(Namespace):
    grammar = binop


class Number(Namespace):
    grammar = number, optional("."), optional(number)


class Expression(Namespace):
    grammar = Number, optional(BinOp, Number)


class Equation(List):
    grammar = Expression, optional("="), optional(Expression)
```

You can handle the error when an invalid expression is passed through and use the parse function to validate expressions:

```
>>> import pypeg2
>>> f = pypeg2.parse("3=3", Equation)
>>> f = pypeg2.parse("3 = 3", Equation)
>>> f = pypeg2.parse("3 + 3 = 3", Equation)
>>> f = pypeg2.parse("3 * 3 = 3", Equation)
>>> f = pypeg2.parse("3hi", Equation)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pypeg2/__init__.py", line 669, in parse
    raise parser.last_error
  File "<string>", line 1
    3hi
     ^
SyntaxError: expecting match on \d+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

input = "1 + 2"

if re.match(r"[\w\s]*[\d\+\-\*\/]+[\w\s]*", input):
    # do whatever you want
    math = re.findall(r"([\d\+\-\*\/]+)", user_input_without_syntax)[0] # if you need that
```